# How is SaveChanges() called in BreezeController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

It appears that all the existing breezejs examples are passing entity models to and from the `BreezeController`.

But almost all our pages built are using some form of view models. In the days we have no BreezeJs, we retrieve the data (domain model) from a repository to populate (using AutoMapper or manually) a view model, which contains only the necessary data for that view. The WebAPI sends only the view model data over to the browser where we can populate a client-side view model (usually a `knockout` observable).

When saving data, we collect data from a `<form>` to populate an input view model, send only that data over to the server, where data in the input view model is mapped to the domain model. The update is saved by calling `SaveChanges()` on the `DbContext` entity in the repository.

Now, `BreezeJs` is to take over all our repository code by creating an `EFContextProvider`. The examples I have seen usually retrieve the domain model data and then pass it all to the client side.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Item> Items() {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Items;
    }
```

It is the client-side javascript's job to build a view model.

Of course it is possible for us to build the view model at the server side:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<ItemViewModel> Items() {
    var items = _contextProvider.Context.Items
                  .Include("RelatedEntity")
                  .ToList();
    var model = new List<ItemViewModel>();
    .... some code to build model from items ....
    return model;
}
```

The benefit is that less data is transferred across the network, and we can do many manipulations on the server side. But I don't know if it is a good practice to modify this `BreezeController` like that. But at least, it returns data needed to list all the items.

The real trouble came when I tried to POST data back.

In the BreezeJs examples I found, they use a `ko.observableArray()` to store all the domain model data, let's say `vm.items`. Then the new record `newItem` is build by `manager.createEntity` into a domain model. After validating the data, `item.entityAspect.validateEntity()`, the `newItem` is pushed into `vm.items` and `manager.saveChanges()` is called, which somehow invokes `SaveChanges()` on the BreezeController.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

I find too many things have been taken over! (Laugh at me if you disagree.) My questions are:

1. Can I just `createEntity` and then `saveChanges`? 
   I only have an empty form to fill in and submit. There is certainly no need to build a whole `items` array on the client-side.
2. Can I pass an input view model as a `JObject` and do some server-side processing before calling `_contextProvider.SaveChanges()`?

---

It turns out to be a super long post again. Thank you for reading it all through. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

Good questions. Unfortunately, our demo code seems to have obscured the real capabilities of Breeze on both client and server. Breeze is not constrained in the ways that your fear.

I don't want to repeat everything that is in our documentation. We really do talk about these issues. We need more examples to be sure.

You are describing a CQRS design. I think it over-complicates most applications. But it's your prerogative.

If you want to send `ItemViewModel` instead of `Item`, you can. If you want that to be treated as an entity on the Breeze client - have the `EntityManager` turn it into a KO observable and manage it in cache, change track it, validate it -, you'll have to provide metadata for it ... either on server or client. That's true for Breeze ... and every other system you can name (Ember, Backbone, etc). Soon we will make it easier to create metadata on the server for an arbitrary CLR model; that may help.

You have complete control over the query on the server, btw, whether `Item` or `ItemViewModel`. You don't have to expose an open-ended query for either. You seem to know that by virtue of your 2nd example query.

On to the **Command** side.

You wrote: "*[the examples] use a ko.observableArray() to store all the domain model data, let's say vm.items*"

That is not precisely true. The items array that you see in examples exists for *presentation*. The items array isn't storing anything from a Breeze perspective. In fact, after a query, the entities returned in the query response (if they are entities) are already in the manager's cache no matter what you do with the query result, whether you put them in an array or throw them away. **An array plays no role whatsoever in the manager's tracking of the entities**.

You wrote: "*Can I just `createEntity` and then `saveChanges`?*"

Of course! The `EntityManager.createEntity` method puts a new entity in cache. Again, the reason you see it being pushed into the `items` array is for presentation to the user. That array has no bearing on what the manager will save.

You wrote: "*Can I pass an input view model ... and do some server-side processing before calling `_contextProvider.SaveChanges()`?*"

I don't know what you mean by "an input viewmodel". The Breeze `EntityManager` tracks entities. If your "input viewmodel" is an entity, the `EntityManager` will track it. If it has changed and you call `saveChanges`, the manager will send it to the controller's `SaveChanges` method.

You own the implementation of the controller's `SaveChanges` method. You can do anything you want with that `JObject` which is simply a JSON.NET representation of the change-set data.  I think you'll benefit from the work that the `ContextProvider` does to parse that object into a `SaveMap`.  Read the [topic on Customizing the EFContextProvider](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider). Most people feel this provides what they need for validating and manipulating the client change-set data before passing those data onto the data access layer ... whether that is EF or something else.

If instead you want to create your own, custom DTO to POST to your own custom controller method ... go right ahead. Don't call `EntityManager.saveChanges` though. Call `EntityManager.getChanges()` and manipulate that change array of entities into your DTO. You'll be doing everything by hand. But you can. Personally, I'd have better things to do.